# Set values to all subsequent rows when a condition is met at current row

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

Following is the base employee table. Combination of emp_id, manager_hierarchy, month_end_date is unique for the table.

```
CREATE TABLE employee_table_base
(
     emp_id        INTEGER NOT NULL,
     manager_hierarchy   INTEGER NOT NULL,
     month_end_date          TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
     assisted_flag VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO employee_table_base(emp_id, manager_hierarchy, month_end_date, assisted_flag)
VALUES
(12345, 1, '2021-10-31', 'N' ),
(12345, 2, '2021-10-31', 'N' ),
(12345, 3, '2021-10-31', 'N' ),
(12345, 1, '2021-11-30', 'Y' ),
(12345, 2, '2021-11-30', 'Y' ),
(12345, 3, '2021-11-30', 'Y' ),
(12345, 1, '2021-12-31', 'Y' ),
(12345, 2, '2021-12-31', 'Y' ),
(12345, 3, '2021-12-31', 'Y' ),
(12345, 1, '2022-01-31', 'Y' ),
(12345, 2, '2022-01-31', 'Y' ),
(12345, 3, '2022-01-31', 'Y' ),
(12345, 1, '2022-02-02', 'Y' ),
(12345, 2, '2022-02-02', 'Y' ),
(12345, 1, '2022-03-31', 'Y' ),
(12345, 2, '2022-03-31', 'Y' ),
(12345, 1, '2022-04-30', 'Y' ),
(12345, 2, '2022-04-30', 'Y' ),
(12345, 1, '2022-05-31', 'Y' ),
(12345, 2, '2022-05-31', 'Y' ),
(12345, 3, '2022-05-31', 'Y' ),
(12345, 1, '2022-06-30', 'N' ),
(12345, 2, '2022-06-30', 'N' ),
(12345, 1, '2022-07-31', 'Y' ),
(12345, 2, '2022-07-31', 'Y' );
```

| emp_id | manager_hierarchy | month_end_date | assisted_flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 1 | 2021-10-31 00:00:00 | N |
| 12345 | 2 | 2021-10-31 00:00:00 | N |
| 12345 | 3 | 2021-10-31 00:00:00 | N |
| 12345 | 1 | 2021-11-30 00:00:00 | Y |
| 12345 | 2 | 2021-11-30 00:00:00 | Y |
| 12345 | 3 | 2021-11-30 00:00:00 | Y |
| 12345 | 1 | 2021-12-31 00:00:00 | Y |
| 12345 | 2 | 2021-12-31 00:00:00 | Y |
| 12345 | 3 | 2021-12-31 00:00:00 | Y |
| 12345 | 1 | 2022-01-31 00:00:00 | Y |
| 12345 | 2 | 2022-01-31 00:00:00 | Y |
| 12345 | 3 | 2022-01-31 00:00:00 | Y |
| 12345 | 1 | 2022-02-02 00:00:00 | Y |
| 12345 | 2 | 2022-02-02 00:00:00 | Y |
| 12345 | 1 | 2022-03-31 00:00:00 | Y |
| 12345 | 2 | 2022-03-31 00:00:00 | Y |
| 12345 | 1 | 2022-04-30 00:00:00 | Y |
| 12345 | 2 | 2022-04-30 00:00:00 | Y |
| 12345 | 1 | 2022-05-31 00:00:00 | Y |
| 12345 | 2 | 2022-05-31 00:00:00 | Y |
| 12345 | 3 | 2022-05-31 00:00:00 | Y |
| 12345 | 1 | 2022-06-30 00:00:00 | N |
| 12345 | 2 | 2022-06-30 00:00:00 | N |
| 12345 | 1 | 2022-07-31 00:00:00 | Y |
| 12345 | 2 | 2022-07-31 00:00:00 | Y |

**Desired output:**

```
drop table if exists employee_table_ouput;
CREATE temp TABLE employee_table_ouput
(
     emp_id        INTEGER NOT NULL,
     manager_hierarchy   INTEGER NOT NULL,
     month_end_date          TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
     assisted_flag VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
     assisted_baseline INTEGER NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO employee_table_ouput(emp_id, manager_hierarchy, month_end_date, assisted_flag, assisted_baseline)
VALUES
(12345, 1, '2021-10-31', 'N', 0 ),
(12345, 2, '2021-10-31', 'N', 0 ),
(12345, 3, '2021-10-31', 'N', 0 ),
(12345, 1, '2021-11-30', 'Y', 0 ),
(12345, 2, '2021-11-30', 'Y', 0 ),
(12345, 3, '2021-11-30', 'Y', 0 ),
(12345, 1, '2021-12-31', 'Y', 1 ),
(12345, 2, '2021-12-31', 'Y', 1 ),
(12345, 3, '2021-12-31', 'Y', 1 ),
(12345, 1, '2022-01-31', 'Y', 1 ),
(12345, 2, '2022-01-31', 'Y', 1 ),
(12345, 3, '2022-01-31', 'Y', 1 ),
(12345, 1, '2022-02-02', 'Y', 1 ),
(12345, 2, '2022-02-02', 'Y', 1 ),
(12345, 1, '2022-03-31', 'Y', 1 ),
(12345, 2, '2022-03-31', 'Y', 1 ),
(12345, 1, '2022-04-30', 'Y', 1 ),
(12345, 2, '2022-04-30', 'Y', 1 ),
(12345, 1, '2022-05-31', 'Y', 1 ),
(12345, 2, '2022-05-31', 'Y', 1 ),
(12345, 3, '2022-05-31', 'Y', 1 ),
(12345, 1, '2022-06-30', 'N', 0 ),
(12345, 2, '2022-06-30', 'N', 0 ),
(12345, 1, '2022-07-31', 'Y', 1 ),
(12345, 2, '2022-07-31', 'Y', 1 );
```

| emp_id | manager_hierarchy | month_end_date | assisted_flag | assisted_baseline |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 1 | 2021-10-31 00:00:00 | N | 0 |
| 12345 | 2 | 2021-10-31 00:00:00 | N | 0 |
| 12345 | 3 | 2021-10-31 00:00:00 | N | 0 |
| 12345 | 1 | 2021-11-30 00:00:00 | Y | 0 |
| 12345 | 2 | 2021-11-30 00:00:00 | Y | 0 |
| 12345 | 3 | 2021-11-30 00:00:00 | Y | 0 |
| 12345 | 1 | 2021-12-31 00:00:00 | Y | 1 |
| 12345 | 2 | 2021-12-31 00:00:00 | Y | 1 |
| 12345 | 3 | 2021-12-31 00:00:00 | Y | 1 |
| 12345 | 1 | 2022-01-31 00:00:00 | Y | 1 |
| 12345 | 2 | 2022-01-31 00:00:00 | Y | 1 |
| 12345 | 3 | 2022-01-31 00:00:00 | Y | 1 |
| 12345 | 1 | 2022-02-02 00:00:00 | Y | 1 |
| 12345 | 2 | 2022-02-02 00:00:00 | Y | 1 |
| 12345 | 1 | 2022-03-31 00:00:00 | Y | 1 |
| 12345 | 2 | 2022-03-31 00:00:00 | Y | 1 |
| 12345 | 1 | 2022-04-30 00:00:00 | Y | 1 |
| 12345 | 2 | 2022-04-30 00:00:00 | Y | 1 |
| 12345 | 1 | 2022-05-31 00:00:00 | Y | 1 |
| 12345 | 2 | 2022-05-31 00:00:00 | Y | 1 |
| 12345 | 3 | 2022-05-31 00:00:00 | Y | 1 |
| 12345 | 1 | 2022-06-30 00:00:00 | N | 0 |
| 12345 | 2 | 2022-06-30 00:00:00 | N | 0 |
| 12345 | 1 | 2022-07-31 00:00:00 | Y | 1 |
| 12345 | 2 | 2022-07-31 00:00:00 | Y | 1 |

The baseline values are always calculated on the last day of the previous year

```
case when month_end_date = date_trunc('year', current_date) - interval '1 day') and assisted_flag = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end as assisted_baseline
```

Is it possible to set all the rows in the current year to 1 whenever assisted_flag = 'Y' and set as 0 whenever assisted_flag = 'N'.
Looking for solution where this can accomplished without self joins.

#### EDIT

If an entry is present on the last day of year('2021-10-31') with assisted_flag = 'Y' only then we should include that primary key as baseline_assisted in the current.

E.g

```
INSERT INTO employee_table_base(emp_id, manager_hierarchy, month_end_date, assisted_flag)
VALUES
(12345, 1, '2021-11-30', 'N' ),
(12345, 2, '2021-11-30', 'N' ),
(12345, 3, '2021-11-30', 'N' ),
(12345, 1, '2021-12-31', 'N' ),
(12345, 2, '2021-12-31', 'N' ),
(12345, 3, '2021-12-31', 'N' ),
(12345, 1, '2022-01-31', 'Y' ),
(12345, 2, '2022-01-31', 'Y' ),
(12345, 3, '2022-01-31', 'Y' ),
(12345, 1, '2022-02-02', 'Y' ),
(12345, 2, '2022-02-02', 'Y' ),
(12345, 1, '2022-03-31', 'Y' ),
(12345, 2, '2022-03-31', 'Y' );
```

| emp_id | manager_hierarchy | month_end_date | assisted_flag | assisted_baseline |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 1 | 2021-11-30 00:00:00 | N | 0 |
| 12345 | 2 | 2021-11-30 00:00:00 | N | 0 |
| 12345 | 3 | 2021-11-30 00:00:00 | N | 0 |
| 12345 | 1 | 2021-12-31 00:00:00 | N | 0 |
| 12345 | 2 | 2021-12-31 00:00:00 | N | 0 |
| 12345 | 3 | 2021-12-31 00:00:00 | N | 0 |
| 12345 | 1 | 2022-01-31 00:00:00 | Y | 0 |
| 12345 | 2 | 2022-01-31 00:00:00 | Y | 0 |
| 12345 | 3 | 2022-01-31 00:00:00 | Y | 0 |
| 12345 | 1 | 2022-02-02 00:00:00 | Y | 0 |
| 12345 | 2 | 2022-02-02 00:00:00 | Y | 0 |
| 12345 | 1 | 2022-03-31 00:00:00 | Y | 0 |
| 12345 | 2 | 2022-03-31 00:00:00 | Y | 0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
select T.emp_id, T.manager_hierarchy, T.month_end_date, T.assisted_flag,
case 
  when (
         month_end_date = date_trunc('year', month_end_date) - interval '1 day' + interval '1 year'
         or 
         exists
              (
                 select 1 from employee_table_base D
                 where D.month_end_date = date_trunc('year', T.month_end_date) - interval '1 day' and
                       D.assisted_flag='Y'
               )
        ) 
        and assisted_flag = 'Y' 
  then 1 else 0 
end as assisted_baseline
from employee_table_base T
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/hF-ruN82).

Comment: Thanks for the solution Ahmed. But as highlighted in the question: "The baseline values are always calculated on the last day of the previous year". So if assisted_flag='N' on the last day of the year, then the records in the current year should *NOT* be marked as assisted_baseline.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it, but when you say 'previous year' do you mean according to the current date or 'month_end_date' value, i.e. for '2021-11-30' the last day of previous year is '2020-12-31'? also should we consider the 'manager_hierarchy' value or whatever the condition is met for any 'manager_hierarchy' value then set  assisted_baseline to 1?

Comment: That is correct. The 'previous year' is relative to 'month_end_date' value. So for '2021-11-30', the last day of the previous year is '2020-12-31' will be used to mark the records as baseline_assisted. 
Secondly, 'manager_hierarchy' does not impact assisted_baseline. Whenever the condition for assisted_baseline is met then mark all the records as 1 for the given emplid.

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. This works perfectly for my use case.
I just had to update 
```sql
month_end_date = date_trunc('year', month_end_date) - interval '1 day' + interval '1 year'
```
to 

```sql
month_end_date = dateadd('year',1,date_trunc('year', month_end_date) - interval '1 day')
```
for redshift.